# Scanf storing value too long, and the second value it reads it stores twice

Tags: c, pointers, struct, scanf

Okay, so I have a program that reads contact information from user input. Here is the function which gets the names of the contact.

```
// getName:
void getName(struct Name* name)
{
    // First name
    printf("Please enter the contact’s first name: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]31s", name->firstName);

    clearKeyboard();

    // Middle Name
    printf("Do you want to enter a middle initial(s)? (y or n): ");
    if (yes()) {
        printf("Please enter the contact’s middle initial(s): ");
        scanf("%[^\n]7s", name->middleInitial);
    }

    clearKeyboard();

    // Last Name
    printf("Please enter the contact’s last name: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]36s", name->lastName);

    clearKeyboard();
}
```

After the contact information is grabbed I display the information and something doesn’t seem right.

What is expected:

```
Name: Tom See John|How Wo|Song Sing
```

What is outputted:

```
Name: Tom See John|How Won|Song Sing Song Sing
```

And here's the declarations for this name struct also:

```
// Structure type Name declaration
struct Name {
    char firstName[31];
    char middleInitial[7];
    char lastName[36];
};
```

Comment: It would improve the question to post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example along with the exact input entered

Comment: None of the `scanf("%[^\n].....` read a `'\n'` nor check the return value of `scanf()`.  `'\n'` is stuck in `stdin` until it is read.  Recommend to switch to `fgets()`.

Comment: `"%[^\n]31s"` is one too big for `char firstName[31];`.  Likely want `" %[^\n]30"`  and check the return value.  Yet even this will not work with a first name like `"Betty Jo"`.